# how to create a BAT file

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd

I want to create a folder named with extracted text from second line of a file.

File content as:

```
Text space space space space space
Text space space space space space
text space space space space space
space space space space space
space space space space space
```

I tried with other files and it seems that I can get the second line. My file is obtained by wmic diskdrive get serialnumber > "sn.txt". There are many spaces in file and can be problems with these spaces. I want to create a folder that have the same name as the HDD series.

Comment: please use our [search box](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+wmic+variable)

Comment: I tried with other files and it seems that I can get the second line.          My file is obtained by wmic diskdrive get serialnumber > "sn.txt".                         There are many spaces in file and can be problems with these spaces.        I want to create a folder that have the same name as the HDD series. THKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need a file; you can get your information directly from the command with a `for` loop:

**EDIT** to take the first serial only, break the loop with a `goto`:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic diskdrive get serialnumber /value^|find "="') do set serial=%%a & goto :done
:done
set serial=%serial: =%
md %serial%
```

(Note: this syntax is for use in batchfiles. If you want to execute it directly from command line, replace each `%%a` with `%a`)

(another note: on my computer there actually *are* spaces in the serialnumber; If you want to remove them, add another line: `set var=%var: =%`)

Comment: I runit and I got:
C:\1>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %a in ('wmic diskdrive get serialnumber /value|f
ind "="') do set var=%a

 :\1>set var=            Z304YWM7

 :\1>set var=44cdc42778336283

 :\1>set var=44cdc40373952219

 :\1>set var=        163613DB0F83

 :\1>set var=

C:\1>echo Serialnumber =
Serialnumber =

Comment: you have more than one disk. How to know which disk to take?

Comment: firs one (Z304YWM7) and yes I want to remove the spaces. I want to create a folder with the HDD serial (Z304YWM7)

Comment: If you add a new HDD it will be the first in the list

Comment: I would like to add a hdd and run command to create a folder named with the serial number